# Passenger nginx on snow leopard not installing via homebrew

Tags: nginx, passenger, osx-snow-leopard, homebrew

Running on OS X 10.6.8.  homebrew installed nginx OK.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.6.0_1
```

But then:

```
brew install passenger nginx --with-passenger
```

as suggested by the passenger documentation (unless there is less recent documentation I should be referring to), I am encountering the following error:

```
passenger: OS X Mountain Lion or newer is required.
```

How can this be overcome?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. We (Phusion) do not support OS X versions older than Mountain Lion. You have several alternatives:

1. Upgrade to the latest OS X version.
2. Use an older version of Phusion Passenger that still supported Mountain Lion. However be aware that it may contain unresolved bugs or have less features. It also cannot be installed from Homebrew: you have to install it from gem or tarball.
3. Take the source of the latest version and modify it so that it works with Mountain Lion.

Comment: You don't support OSX Mountain Lion? Then why does the error message say " OS X Mountain Lion or newer is required". -1 for such a sloppy post. It also might be helpful to post the last version of Passenger that supported 10.6.8 don'cha think? –

Comment: I said it wrong. I meant "don't support mountain_lion - 1" since the poster is clearly on pre-mountain lion. I'll leave it up to you to correct my post and to figure out which version was the last that supported pre-mountain lion. If you'll excuse me, I'll go back to writing and debugging complicated C++ code instead of providing support.

Comment: RE point 2: I couldn't find a reference to Snow Leopard support being removed in the changelog, but based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25241935/1714), I installed v4.0.5 (from gem), which worked for me.  I didn't bother testing versions between 4.0.5 and 4.0.48 (which fails with an "Undefined symbols" error)

Comment: It's not so much that we removed Snow Leopard support on purpose. It's that we -- the developers -- upgrade OS X from time to time. Eventually, Passenger just doesn't work on older versions anymore because of compiler differences etc, because we've lost the ability to test on those older versions.